A few questions about the perpendicularity of the gradient to a contour line of the function
I'm taking a small course which is sort of like a course on multivariable calculus, where the emphasis is more on intuition and computational skills than rigor, and later I will be taking a more rigorous real-analysis like course which covers these topics. And there are a few things that I don't entirely understand in the following situation:
Given a differentiable function $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, and a contour line $l := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | f(x,y)=c\} \subseteq D$, for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $(x_0,y_0) \in l$. Then for any point $(x,y) \in l$, since $f$ is constant on $l$, it follows that $df = 0$ and therefore
$$0=df=\underline{\nabla} f \big\rvert_{(x_0,y_0)}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} dx \\ dy\end{pmatrix},$$
and hence $\underline{\nabla} f \big\rvert_{(x_0,y_0)} \perp \begin{pmatrix} dx \\ dy\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0\end{pmatrix}$, and as we take closer and closer points $(x,y) \in l$ to $(x_0, y_0)$, the vector $\begin{pmatrix} dx \\ dy\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0\end{pmatrix}$ "becomes" tangent to $l$ at the point $(x_0, y_0)$.
So, I have a few questions about this argument on a more conceptual / intuitive level - no need to get super rigorous:

Did I state this argument as well as you would expect from a not fully rigorous multi-variable calculus course, or are there any serious errors in what I've written?
If the answer to 1. is yes, then the main thing which is not entirely clear to me is why does it follows that $df=0$? Suppose for example that we define $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$, where $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$, by $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ for every $(x,y) \in D$. Then, we have for example the contour line $l := \{(x,y) \in D | f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2 + y^2 = \frac{3}{4}\}$, and we have the point $(x_0,y_0) := \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},0\right) \in l$. Now lets take another point $(x,y)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 0\right) \in l$. Then we have:
$$df=\underline{\nabla} f \big\rvert_{(x_0,y_0)}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} dx \\ dy\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2-y_0^2}} \\ -\frac{y_0}{\sqrt{1-x_0^2-y_0^2}}\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} x-x_0 \\ y-y_0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{3} \\ 0\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{3} \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = -3 \neq 0.$$
So what's going on here? Doesn't this example contradict the arguement? What is the flaw with my example?
Finally, my last question is does this "theorem" goes both ways? That is, if  we know that the differential $df$ is $0$ for every point $(x_0, y_0)$ along some curve in the domain and any other point $(x,y)$ in this curve, does it follows then that this curve is a contour line, i.e. $f$ is constant along this curve? My lecturer didn't really state this clearly, but it seems like we need to know this in order to solve a certain question in the homework.

